# Wire with multiple modules

Tags: verilog

I am trying to simulate a really basic memory model by having multiple memory blocks (initiations of a basic module) and tying the output of all those blocks to one wire. Is this the way to do this?

```
module memoryBlock(
 input Enable,
 output [7:0] dataOut,
 input [7:0] dataIN
);

always @(*) begin
  if(Enable == 1)
    dataOut = dataIn;

end

endmodule;
```

The idea is that only one of these data blocks would be enabled at a time, and then I could pass whatever information was in the enabled block to the output wire. Here is how I would use it:

```
module testbench;
  reg [7:0] exampleData1 = 8'b00000001;
  reg [7:0] exampleData2 = 8'b11111111;
  reg enable1 = 0;
  reg enable2 = 1;
  wire [7:0] outputForBoth;

memoryBlock mb1(enable1, outputForBoth, exampleData1);
memoryBlock mb2(enable2, outputForBoth, exampleData2);

endmodule;
```

When I have tried sample stuff like this before the output has just been 'zzzzzzzz'. My goal is to be able to have multiple memory blocks.. only enable one of them, and have that wire hold whatever data from that block. Is this the correct approach? Any help would be huge!

This way I only have one place I need to go to retrieve all of the output information. The other way I thought to do this was building a MUX of some sorts, and it just seems a lot more complicated that it needs to be!

Comment: Your approach is not correct, since wire (i.e. `outputForBoth`) can't be driven by multiple drivers (i.e. output signals from `mb1` and `mb2`).

Comment: Is there a way to drive something from multiple signals? @qiu

Comment: Yes, it's called a tri-state buffer, checkout last figure here: https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/CompOrg/tristate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need tri-state outputs to do this. Tri-states drive a wire when enabled and are at high impedance state when not. But you need to make sure that you don't enable two modules at the same time.

```
module memoryBlock(
 input enable,
 inout [7:0] dataOut,
 input [7:0] dataIN
);

    assign dataOut = enable? dataIn : 8'bzzzzzzzz;


endmodule
```